# Tasks/Todo list for WP8

Tags: apps

is there any tasks/todo app for WP8 where I could manage my task from WP8 and internet page? 
In Android there is gmail todo list and apps that can integrate with it. I'm looking for something familiar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I highly recommend using the task lists that are part of Windows Live Calendar.

**To access it on your desktop:**

1. Go to the [Windows Live Calendar](http://calendar.live.com) site
2. Choose "Task" from the meny on the top right

[image]

**To access it on Windows Phone 8:**

1. Go to the Calendar app
2. Swipe to the right to see the "To-do" view

[image]

---

Reference: [Windows Phone Guide- Using Calendars](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-ca/how-to/wp8/people/use-calendars)

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation is to use OneNote. I've tried all manner of task management systems in the past, and I've found that OneNote provides the most flexibility of all of them. It's built in to WP, syncs wonderfully with the cloud, you can edit your OneNote docs online at skydrive.com, and there are apps for iPhone and Android.